# what is the fasest method to communicate between pthreads on linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a pthreads app that I currently use regular linux pipes to communicate and send messages to the various threads.  Its works fine and is not really broken but I have a nagging feeling that it can be improved.

If I want to design for the least latency, what is the **fastest** method to communicate between pthreads?  Would using condition variables be faster than pipes?

I need to pass small amounts of data, as a single int optcode with a few parameters. Will pthreads condition variables let me pass data between threads?

Thanks,

-Andres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's between threads then either shared memory or a lock free queue would be quite a bit faster.

The choice between which to choose will depend on the data you're passing around.  A static buffer shared between two threads guarded by a lock is fine.  Where you are generating data and passing it to another thread perhaps a queue is a better choice.

Some implementations of bounded lockfree MPMC queues are available here: http://www.1024cores.net

By the way, be careful writing your own lock free data structures.  They are not as trivial as you might expect to get right.  A locking version will be a good start and will still out-perform pipes.

Between processes linux pipes as you call them (or unix domain sockets are a good option).

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage to using threads rather than separate processes is that they share memory.  Sending data through a pipe requires a round-trip through the kernel, whereas using a shared memory buffer in conjunction with a mutex and condition variable can avoid this - certainly it should have lower latency than using pipes.

You do not use the condition variable to directly pass the data of interest.  Instead, the data is placed into a memory location shared by the two threads, and a condition variable is used to wake the thread that is waiting for the data to arrive.